# slot machine game c# image Values

Tags: c#, arrays

im doing a slot machine game , its a simple one , that basically it will roll the image in the picurebox into a random image.  using this code

```
PictureBox[] PictureboxArray = new PictureBox[5];
```

the 5 picureboxes are assigned using this line of code

```
PictureboxArray[0] = pbxK;
            PictureboxArray[1] = pbxQueen;
            PictureboxArray[2] = pbxKing;
            PictureboxArray[3] = pbxJoker;
            PictureboxArray[4] = pbxAce;
```

Images are assigned like that

```
Image[] Rollimage = new Image[5];
            Rollimage[0] = Properties.Resources.K;
            Rollimage[1] = Properties.Resources.Queen;
            Rollimage[2] = Properties.Resources.King;
            Rollimage[3] = Properties.Resources.Joker;
            Rollimage[4] = Properties.Resources.Ace;
```

and the intial image of the picturebox are assigned like that

```
            pbxK.Image = Rollimage[0];
            pbxQueen.Image = Rollimage[1];
            pbxKing.Image = Rollimage[2];
            pbxJoker.Image = Rollimage[3];
            pbxAce.Image = Rollimage[4];
```

the actual code for the image rolling is as follows

```
for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                if (PictureboxArray[i].Enabled == true)
                {

                    Roll[i] = Rnd.Next(0, 4);
                }
                PictureboxImage(PictureboxArray[i], Roll[i]); 
            }
```

rnd is a new random

```
Random Rnd = new Random();
```

Roll in an int for saving the index of the roll

```
int[] Roll = new int[5];
```

everything works fine and the pictures rolls different image every second of the time , as I predefined that, now what im trying to do is to assign this

```
 int[] PictureValues = new int[]{100, 225, 550, 775, 1000};
```

to the images

```
Image[] Rollimage = new Image[5];
```

meaning that the first roll image which is `Properties.Resources.K;`has the actual value of 100
and so on , is there a way to do that ?

Comment: You just want to change the name they are accessed by?

Comment: Bit confused what the problem is.  You are wanting to associate a value with each index in the array, and you have a parallel array with values.  So.. for `RollImage[i]` you have a value of `PictureValues[i]`  Are you wanting to actually assign the value into the image object so that you do not have two separate arrays?

Comment: what im trying to do simply is that after the images stops rolling , the program check what image in the picturebox and then check the value of that image then add it to the total E.G if it was `Rollimage[0] = Properties.Resource.K` Then it has the value 100 From `int[] PictureValues = new int[]{100, 225, 550, 775, 1000};`

Comment: You can use attributes and enums to do what you want i think. Look at the answer to this question and see if that helps you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10307459/keep-enum-to-object-mapping-with-enum-class

Comment: i couldnt find what i need for , its like really simple process , i tried using if statements , like
`if (pbxK.Image == Rollimage[0] || pbxQueen.Image == Rollimage[0] || pbxKing.Image == Rollimage[0] || pbxJoker.Image == Rollimage[0] || pbxAce.Image == Rollimage[0])
{
TempTotal += 100;
}`
 didnt work at all

Comment: Encapsulate your images into a class that defines everything and handles the rolling. The class will contain the value of each card as well maybe in a separate array of values corresponding the array of images.

Answer (score 0):

So.. if I understand your issue correctly, once the image is selected, you need a way to reverse it back to associate it with a value.  One method could be the following:

Note:  It appears that each picturebox that is showing, is named king / joker etc.. so if you are looking at the front of the 'slot machine' you see 5 boxes which are named pbxk, pbxQueen, pbxKing, pbxJoker, pbxAce but they don't necessarily display the image associated with their name..

```
int total = 0;
for(int i=0;i<Rollimage.Length;i++)
{
    if(pbxk.Image.Equals(Rollimage[i]))
    {
        total += PictureValues[i];
    }
    if(pbxQueen...)
    {
        //Do the same thing for each pbx
    }
}
```

The only thing I'm not 100% on is the comparison method.  Additionally, you could use the picturebox's ImageLocation property to store the path to the image whenever you assign it, and then compare that against a filename to figure out what image is showing.

Example on how to compare images:  [Stack Overflow Image Compare](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22364723/if-picturebox-image-properties-resources-imagea)

Given that example, you may want to try == using your current Image array.. if that doesn't work, you may need to define an array of bitmaps to compare against.  Seems like a waste of memory to me, but it should work.

***Edit***

The following code sums the values of the images correctly.  I just put together a quick sample program with 2 pictureboxes, a control button and a label, with two resources.  This should demonstrate all of the techniques required to perform what you are needing.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    PictureBox[] PictureboxArray = new PictureBox[2];
    Image[] Rollimage = new Image[2];
    int[] pictureValues = new int[2];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureValues[0] = 100;
        pictureValues[1] = 200;

        Rollimage[0] = Properties.Resources.TitleBar;
        Rollimage[1] = Properties.Resources.Untitled;

        PictureboxArray[0] = this.pictureBox1;
        PictureboxArray[1] = this.pictureBox2;
        PictureboxArray[1].Image = Rollimage[0];
        PictureboxArray[0].Image = Rollimage[0];
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int total = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<Rollimage.Length;i++)
        {
            foreach(var box in PictureboxArray)
            {
                if(box.Image == Rollimage[i])
                {
                    total += pictureValues[i];
                }
            }
        }
        label1.Text = total.ToString();
    }
}
```

Comment: no luck at all :( , ive been trying for 5 days so far  ,like 8 hours a day to figure out this i just cant , its pretty sure its simple but i just cant get to solve it ...

Comment: I will draft up an example when I get back to a computer with vs and see if we can't get somewhere with this.  Image comparison shouldnt be too difficult all thinga considered.  I will try and post an update here in about an hour

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH ! Thats actually makes sense of what im making, ill give it try today and give you feedback asap

Comment: OKAY Nate , everything works fine as intended , you are  legend , but your code will only work if the pictures are static and not rolled into different images , i have a rolling command , which is this 
`for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++)
            {
                    Roll[i] = Rnd.Next(0, 5);
                PictureboxImage(PictureboxArray[i], Roll[i]);
         }`

Comment: The code snippet above was not intended to solve your entire problem, but rather demonstrate the principles behind how to go about solving your problem.  The code is very easily extended to solve the slightly more complex problem of a cycling array of images.  Again, the snippet above demonstrates all principles associated with solving your coding problem, given a small amount of customization.

Comment: Yess nate thank you i got to work thanks a lot maaaaan